# Problem in running vlc in Openindiana

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc, illumos, openindiana

3 days ago I upgraded vlc in Openindiana hipster 2018.04  .

The problem is that vlc will open but cannot play anything.

I thought that it is due to ffmpeg package

So, I removed my ffmpeg by

```
pkg://sfe-encumbered/video/ffmpeg
pkg://sfe-encumbered/library/video/ffmpeg
pkg://sfe-encumbered/media/mplayer2
smplayer
pkg://sfe-encumbered/media/vlc
```

and then reinstalled it

```
/usr/bin/pkg install pkg://sfe-encumbered/video/ffmpeg@0.8.5 mplayer2 smplayer media/vlc
```

But the problem is still same

Answer (score 0):

Install VLC from the official encumbered OpenIndiana repository

pkg.openindiana.org/hipster-encumbered

and not from third party repositories which contains possibly unmaintained packages.
This is not a problem with OpenIndiana but with SFE.

Also better post to the OpenIndiana mailing list if you want to get answers.